# I'm attempting to attached 2 separate pages with `afterscreenupdated:YES`

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm attempting to attach two separate screens in Xcode by way of `afterscreenupdated:YES`, and I'm unfamiliar with that line of code since I'm pretty new to code writing & app creating. All I'm trying to do is set it to where once you open the app, you press a button, and it takes you to a form screen. I have both screens built, I'm just working on connecting them.

Currently, the button only takes you to a page displaying the name of the second page, but not the content of the page. I'm not sure where the `afterscreenupdated:YES` goes or even really the function of the code.

This is the error being displayed at the bottom of my screen in the console:
`Snapshotting a view (0x1046108c0, _UIButtonBarStackView) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.`

I've searched for a tutorial and haven't found any helpful ones yet. Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

**Screen 1 Code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView(content: {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("PCRPage")) { Text("New PCR") }
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.all)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Rectangle())
                .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .cornerRadius(20)

        })
    
    
        HStack(content: {
            Text("PCR Mobile")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
        })

    }
    func PCR() {
        // PCR is the function for the button "New PCR"
        print("New PCR")
        }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

**Screen 2 Code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct PCRPage: View {


    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {

 -- insert unimportant page content here --
            
            }
        } 
    
    } //End of ScrollView
}

struct PCRPage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PCRPage()
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the contents of the second page to be displayed on the phone screen once the button is clicked. I've tried messing around with it, looking for a tutorial, and have thus far been unsuccessful.